# Generic type narrowing via the "is" operator and conditional types

Tags: typescript

I want to use the `is` operator to narrow a generic type to either a "union of primitive types" or simply the `object` type. Either way would work for my use case.

What's the proper workaround for the following snippet? ([playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%3CT%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(value%3A%20(()%20%3D%3E%20T)%20%7C%20(T%20extends%20Function%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T))%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Function%20values%20must%20be%20returned%20by%20a%20getter%3A%0D%0Anew%20Foo(()%20%3D%3E%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D)%20%2F%2F%20OK%3A%20Inferred%20as%20%22Foo%3C()%20%3D%3E%20void%3E(value%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20()%20%3D%3E%20void)%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20All%20other%20values%20can%20be%20optionally%20wrapped%20with%20a%20getter%2C%20or%20passed%20as-is%3A%0D%0Anew%20Foo(()%20%3D%3E%201)%20%2F%2F%20OK%3A%20Inferred%20as%20%22Foo%3C1%3E(value%3A%201%20%7C%20(()%20%3D%3E%201))%22%0D%0Anew%20Foo(1)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20OK%3A%20Inferred%20as%20%22Foo%3C1%3E(value%3A%201%20%7C%20(()%20%3D%3E%201))%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Try%20narrowing%20to%20a%20primitive%20type%3A%0D%0Afunction%20testPrimitive%3CT%3E(value%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isPrimitive(value))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Foo(value)%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%20%22Type%20'T%20%26%20string'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'T%20%26%20symbol%20extends%20Function%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T%20%26%20symbol'.%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Try%20narrowing%20to%20an%20object%20type%3A%0D%0Afunction%20testObject%3CT%3E(value%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isObject(value))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Foo(value)%20%2F%2F%20ERROR%3A%20%22Type%20'T%20%26%20object'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'T%20%26%20object%20extends%20Function%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20T%20%26%20object'.%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Primitive%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20symbol%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20undefined%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20isPrimitive%20%3D%20(value%3A%20any)%3A%20value%20is%20Primitive%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20!value%20%7C%7C%20typeof%20value%20!%3D%3D%20'object'%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20isObject%20%3D%20(value%3A%20any)%3A%20value%20is%20object%20%3D%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20value%20%26%26%20typeof%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20'object'%0D%0A))

```
class Foo<T = any> {
    constructor(value: (() => T) | (T extends Function ? never : T)) {}
}

// Function values must be returned by a getter:
new Foo(() => () => {}) // OK: Inferred as "Foo<() => void>(value: () => () => void)"

// All other values can be optionally wrapped with a getter, or passed as-is:
new Foo(() => 1) // OK: Inferred as "Foo<1>(value: 1 | (() => 1))"
new Foo(1)       // OK: Inferred as "Foo<1>(value: 1 | (() => 1))"

// Try narrowing to a primitive type:
function testPrimitive<T>(value: T) {
    if (isPrimitive(value)) {
        return new Foo(value) // ERROR: "Type 'T & string' is not assignable to type 'T & symbol extends Function ? never : T & symbol'."
    }
}

// Try narrowing to an object type:
function testObject<T>(value: T) {
    if (isObject(value)) {
        return new Foo(value) // ERROR: "Type 'T & object' is not assignable to type 'T & object extends Function ? never : T & object'."
    }
}

type Primitive = string | number | boolean | symbol | null | undefined

const isPrimitive = (value: any): value is Primitive =>
    !value || typeof value !== 'object'

const isObject = (value: any): value is object =>
    value && typeof value === 'object'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define the basics:

```
type Primitive = boolean | number | string | symbol | null | undefined;


class Foo<T> {
    constructor(value: T | (T extends Function ? never : T)) {}
}

new Foo(() => 1)
new Foo(1)
```

If we define `isPrimitive` and `isObject` as such:

```
declare function isPrimitive(argument: unknown): argument is Primitive;
declare function isObject<T extends object>(argument: T | Primitive): argument is T;
```

we get correct type inference at the call site:

```
function testPrimitive(argument: unknown) {
    if (isPrimitive(argument)) {
        return new Foo(argument);
    }
}

function testObject<T extends object>(argument: T | Primitive) {
    if (isObject(argument)) {
        return new Foo(argument);
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Primitive%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20boolean%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20number%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20symbol%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20null%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20isPrimitive(argument%3A%20unknown)%3A%20argument%20is%20Primitive%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20isObject%3CT%20extends%20object%3E(argument%3A%20T%20%7C%20Primitive)%3A%20argument%20is%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Thunk%3CT%3E%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(value%3A%20T%20%7C%20Thunk%3CT%3E)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Foo(()%20%3D%3E%201)%0D%0Anew%20Foo(1)%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testPrimitive%3CT%3E(argument%3A%20T%20%7C%20Primitive)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isPrimitive(argument))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Foo(argument)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20testObject%3CT%20extends%20object%3E(argument%3A%20T%20%7C%20Primitive)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(isObject(argument))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Foo(argument)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)